# Python Multiple variables has one Value

Tags: python, variables, null

How can i make this code pretty?:

```
    AantalCores = "NULL"
    CPUSSpecNumber = "NULL"
    Snelheid = "NULL"
    MaximaleTurboFrequentie = "NULL"
    GeheugenSpecificatie = "NULL"
    BusSnelheid = "NULL"
    Procestechnologie = "NULL"
    ThermalDesignPower = "NULL"
    GeïntegreerdeGraphics = "NULL"
    Gpu = "NULL"
    NominaleSnelheidVideochip = "NULL"
    MaximaleSnelheidVideochip = "NULL"
    CPUCacheLevel1 = "NULL"
    CPUCacheLevel2 = "NULL"
    CPUCacheLevel3 = "NULL"
    Threads = "NULL"
    Virtualisatie = "NULL"
    VirtualisatieType = "NULL"
    CPUMultiplier = "NULL"
    CPUstepping = "NULL"
    CPUInstructieset = "NULL"
    TypeKoeling = "NULL"
```

Changed the whole thing. I've watched your answers guys, Thanx a lot!
I'm almost finished, i only have to iterate properly. Can you guys show me a better way that WORKS ( mine doesn't:

```
    if componentTitle == 'Processoren':

        properties = {'AantalCores': 'NULL', 'CPUSSpecNumber': 'NULL', 'Snelheid': 'NULL', 'MaximaleTurboFrequentie': 'NULL', 'GeheugenSpecificatie': 'NULL', 'BusSnelheid': 'NULL', 'Procestechnologie': 'NULL', 'ThermalDesignPower': 'NULL', 'GeïntegreerdeGraphics': 'NULL', 'Gpu': 'NULL', 'NominaleSnelheidVideochip': 'NULL', 'MaximaleSnelheidVideochip': 'NULL', 'CPUCacheLevel1': 'NULL', 'CPUCacheLevel2': 'NULL', 'CPUCacheLevel3': 'NULL', 'Threads': 'NULL', 'Virtualisatie': 'NULL', 'VirtualisatieType': 'NULL', 'CPUMultiplier': 'NULL', 'CPUstepping': 'NULL', 'CPUInstructieset': 'NULL', 'TypeKoeling': 'NULL'}

        if spec.get_text(strip=True) == 'Processorkernen': properties['AantalCores'] = value.text.strip()
        elif spec.get_text(strip=True) == 'Kloksnelheid': properties['Snelheid'] = value.text.strip()
        elif spec.get_text(strip=True) == 'Threads': properties['Threads'] = value.text.strip()

        # I NEED TO ITERATE AL THE KEYS/VALUES INTO THIS NODE (product)
        for key in properties:
            product = Node("Component", 'CPU', key=properties[key])
```

So i have to declare the values first. Or else the values aren't saved into the Neo4J Database. Also None is not alright. It skips it. After the properties are defined, i'm changing ONLY the Values it crosses. Some Pages don't have the same Key/Values. So after editing, i need to make it a Node-Object so i can Save it with a Relationship:

```
# CREATE RELATIONSHIP NODE OBJECT
rel = relationNode.rel('Relationship', product, store, price, stock)
db.create(rel)
```

Comment: Why are you setting all these to `"NULL"`? First off, Python's empty value is `None`, secondly, you don't need to initialize variables in Python...

Comment: It's because i am trying  to put these values in a Neo4J Database. It HAS to be in there as properties. If i use None it doesn't even saves it, it skips the property and i don't have it in the Database

Comment: can those be keys in a dict instead of variables? that would make it easier

Comment: It doesn't allow dictionaries, i've tried that at first

Comment: Well, i have to iterate through the dictionary to get all the key/values. So i can save the (product)node to my database

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Something along of what you tried

> AantalCores,CPUSSpecNumber,Snelheid,MaximaleTurboFrequentie,GeheugenSpecificatie,BusSnelheid,Procestechnologie,ThermalDesignPower,GeïntegreerdeGraphics,Gpu,NominaleSnelheidVideochip,MaximaleSnelheidVideochip,CPUCacheLevel1,CPUCacheLevel2,CPUCacheLevel3,Threads,Virtualisatie,VirtualisatieType,CPUMultiplier,CPUstepping,CPUInstructieset,TypeKoeling = ["NULL"]*22

```
print AantalCores
print CPUSSpecNumber
print Snelheid
```

output

```
null
null
null
```

Comment: This will work... but seriously, don't do this. It's generally a bad idea to code anything that will later require you to count items in a list. :-)

Comment: Yes, i agree, but i think this is what the OP was trying to do originally

Comment: This is an acceptable answer in only a very few strict circumstances. It's good as a hack to make it work, but if I had to maintain something coded this way I would force my children and my children's children to swear never to be a friend to Original Coder.

Comment: Yes, i also now agree ^__^

Comment: Improved my question, can you please check once more?

Comment: I agree that this isn't the best approach, but how am I getting down voted if I only answered what the Op was trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

You might be better off using a dictionary than a bunch of separate variables:

```
FIELDS = {k: "NULL" for k in (
    "AantalCores",
    "CPUSSpecNumber",
    "Snelheid",
    # ... etc.
)}
```

Then you can access them with e.g. `FIELDS["AantalCores"]`, or if you need to deal with all of them later in your code, something like:

```
for name, value in FIELDS.items():
    # do something with name and value
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I'd call it *better*, but here's one way you could do multi-assign...

```
AantalCores = CPUSSpecNumber = Snelheid = MaximaleTurboFrequentie = "NULL"
GeheugenSpecificatie = BusSnelheid = Procestechnologie = ThermalDesignPower = "NULL"
```

And so on...

**UPDATE:**

Following up on the comments below...

Generally, it's not a good idea to do this... but if you had a *large* number of names you needed to assign all at once, you could start with them in a dict, e.g.:

```
d = {'AantalCores': 'NULL', 'CPUSSSpecNumber': 'NULL'}
```

And then when you're done manipulating them in the dict and need them to be named values, you can add them to your locals thus:

```
import sys
this_module = sys.modules[__name__]
for key, value in d.items():
    setattr(this_module, key, value)
```

But truly, this is not the way you should manage your names in ordinary cases and the dict-only approach should be your method of first resort in any case where it would actually work.

Comment: This works well for immutable values such as strings or numbers. Don't try it on mutable values such as lists though, unless you like surprises.

Comment: I was taking the OP's objective at face value, but that's a good point in the general case.

Comment: Improved my question, can you please check once more?

Comment: @FrEaKi Taking at face value that you need named values, then you'll need to assign these names somehow. You've got a couple OK options to choose from. There are more arcane ways to mass-assign names, but that would just be more confusing for the number of items you've got here.

Comment: This list will be much bigger. These are just the examples which i'm trying to get to work. I only need to iterate the right way to get for example this: btc = Node('BTC', 'Bitstamp', timestamp=timestamp, low=low, high=high, ask=ask, bid=bid, last=last, volume=volume, vwap=vwap)

Comment: @FrEaKi I updated the answer to show you another method for a much larger case. For use only where the dictionary approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can hold all those values in a single array like this:

```
something = {
        "ID": 1280,
        "Another ID": "NULL",
    }
```

And you can change all the values with a single loop for or one by one:

```
for val in something:
    something[val] = "null or your value"

something["ID"] = 900000
```

I hope this will help you, sorry for the bad english.